# When and Why did "Sooner than Later" become a thing?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

Three times in the past week or so I came across somebody writing "sooner than later" when what they obviously meant was "sooner *rather* than later." The first time I saw it, I thought it was a typo. The second time was by the same writer, and I realized he was doing it deliberately. So I thought it was just a quirk of this cat; then I saw it again by someone else.

I'm not against change, but "sooner than later" doesn't even make sense. How did it become accepted practice to drop the "RATHER"?

Comment: When you're learning English, final ER's are a thing. When you're learning a phrase with three of them -_soonER rathER than latER_, stuff gets left out. and  the middle ER, the non-parallel one, is the likeliest candidate for leaving out. Consider that _sooner_ and _later_ are both comparatives (and the comparative word _than_ separates them), while the word _rather_ **means** 'comparative'. The phrase shouts **COMPARATIVE!** That's overspecification, and people can spot it, and learn to live without it.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided the full sentences or contexts in which this phrase occurs.  There is a phrase 'sooner OR later', which means 'eventually'.  I could imagine someone using the phrase you mention because they want something done not 'sooner or later', but 'sooner THAN later'.  That would be quite an effective way of making a point.  But I do not know the context.

Comment: I’ve never heard anyone speak or write this. I agree with @Tuffy - context would be helpful here.

Comment: I can vouch, from anecdotal experience, that using "sooner than later" in contexts where I would expect "sooner rather than later" has recently become common in my work correspondence (tech, Pacific Northwest, USA).  OP's not imagining it. On the other hand, from 7 years ago:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118298/whats-the-verdict-on-sooner-than-later

Comment: @A_S00 Perhaps we should describe it as a 'transitional' usage:  not yet 'established' but not in error.  "sooner than", in that context looks grammatically sound.  'It don't want your response later; I want it sooner than later'.  Beyond that you could, if you wanted to, account for it as ellipse (dropping the word 'rather'); but that is more a question of the psychology of the user than one of strict grammar.

Comment: I don't know where the exact original sources are, but in the two cases by the same person, he is a professional writer. His name is Wes Hodkiewicz and he writes (on alternate days) the "Insiders Inbox" on the Green Bay Packers web site. I don't think his counterpart (Mike Spofford) would be caught dead using "sooner than later," though. I don't recall where the third instance of it that I ran across was.

Comment: FWIW, I never heard it when I was young, and I too hear it a lot now. I wonder if it might have been used in some region of the US when I was young and has now gotten more widespread use. (I have the same feeling about "long story short" instead of "to make a long story short".)

Comment: The same cat (professional writer) also just wrote "cut and dry" instead of "cut and dried." Many people write that way because they never read, and they write what they (think they) hear, but for a professional writer to do that seems odd to me.